# Livepatch reporting trojan based on Trend - Trojan.Linux.EMPEROR.USELVK623

Tags: malware, antivirus, canonical-livepatch

we have a bunch of machines that are currently flagging a trojan in the livepatch update.

Trend is reporting an issue in:
/snap/canonical-livepatch/248/canonical-livepatch
/snap/canonical-livepatch/248/canonical-livepatchd

Think that its a false positive but has anyone else seen this?

VirusTotal links:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/67aa2b640d4685bfc058a67630ed677a8334ef9a502331ae643e5de31503c2d3/detection
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/0a5c8459e24b81898e1bcc05bd600372c11651f7b7ad8132d479b756e3ca3b46/detection